# The image is not updating on the webpage despite successful AJAX requests using Flask

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask

I'm currently working on a personal project that has this python function to update an image on a webpage for a specific amount of time. The output indicates that the image was successfully retrieved but it doesn't get updated on the actual webpage. Here's the script for both:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Viewer</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Image Viewer</h1>
    <img id="image-display" src="{{ url_for('static', filename=current_images) }}" alt="Random Image">
    <br>
    <button id="update-button">Update Image</button>
    <div id="countdown">5</div>

    <script>
        // Function to update the image using Ajax
        function updateImage() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url_for('update_image') }}",
                method: "GET",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#image-display").attr("src", data.current_images);
                }
            });
        }

        // Function to handle the button click
        function handleButtonClick() {
            var countdown = 5;

            // Update the countdown and the image every 0.2 seconds
            var countdownInterval = setInterval(function() {
                $("#countdown").text(countdown);
                
                if (countdown === 0) {
                    clearInterval(countdownInterval);
                    $("#countdown").text("");
                } else {
                    updateImage();
                    countdown--;
                }
            }, 200);
        }

        // Attach click event to the button
        $("#update-button").click(function() {
            handleButtonClick();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**App.py**

```
import random
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

image_list = ['img model/Talk1Eh.png','img model/Talk1Mmm.png', 'img model/Talk1OpenMouth_Oh.png',
            'img model/Talk1OpenMouthA.png', 'img model/Talk1OpenMouthHA.png']

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', current_images = random.choice(image_list))

@app.route('/update_image')
def update_image():
    current_images = random.choice(image_list)
    print(current_images)
    return render_template('index.html', current_images = current_images)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Debug Outputs**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2023 21:26:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2023 21:26:28] "GET /static/img%20model/Talk1OpenMouth_Oh.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
img model/Talk1Eh.png
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2023 21:26:30] "GET /update_image HTTP/1.1" 200 -
img model/Talk1Mmm.png
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2023 21:26:30] "GET /update_image HTTP/1.1" 200 -
img model/Talk1Eh.png
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2023 21:26:30] "GET /update_image HTTP/1.1" 200 -
img model/Talk1OpenMouthHA.png
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2023 21:26:31] "GET /update_image HTTP/1.1" 200 -
img model/Talk1Eh.png
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2023 21:26:31] "GET /update_image HTTP/1.1" 200 -
img model/Talk1OpenMouthA.png
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2023 21:26:33] "GET /update_image HTTP/1.1" 200 -
img model/Talk1OpenMouthHA.png
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2023 21:26:33] "GET /update_image HTTP/1.1" 200 -
img model/Talk1Mmm.png
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2023 21:26:33] "GET /update_image HTTP/1.1" 200 -
img model/Talk1Mmm.png
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2023 21:26:34] "GET /update_image HTTP/1.1" 200 -
img model/Talk1OpenMouthHA.png
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2023 21:26:34] "GET /update_image HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the URLs of the randomly selected images via AJAX.

In your attempt, however, you obtain the entire template again. This does not have a `current_images` property because it contains the rendered HTML code and not a JavaScript object. This and the fact that the `static` folder within the respective URL was ignored means that the images cannot be loaded.

I recommend that you send the URLs in JSON format after you have created the complete URL in the usual way with `url_for`.

```py
from flask import jsonify, url_for

# ...

@app.route('/update_image')
def update_image():
    current_images = random.choice(image_list)
    print(current_images)
    return jsonify(current_images=url_for('static', filename=current_images))
```